# Equation in epidemic SIR model with the influence of vaccinations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, epidemics-modeling

I am currently preparing a presentation on different modifications of the [SIR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology). In my sources about the use of vaccines, I came across the following model for a specific rate at which the population is vaccinated.

---

> **Concurrent Vaccination** In contrast to the previous vaccination scenario we now assume that public health steps up only at the onset of an outbreak,
> $$\begin{aligned} \dot S &= -\beta \frac{S I}{N} - \psi (S, I) \\ \dot I &= \beta \frac{S I}{N} - \alpha I \\ \dot R &= \alpha I + \psi (S, I) \end{aligned} \tag{6.49} $$
> There are different outcomes depending on the choice of the function $\psi$. Assume $\psi (S, I) = \psi S I$ with some number $\psi > 0$. Then the number of remaining susceptible $S_{\infty}$ is independent of $\psi$, however the total size of the epidemic is reduced to
> $$ T = \frac{\beta}{\beta + \psi} \left( 1 - S_{\infty} \right). \tag{6.50} $$
> On the other hand, if we assume $\psi (S, I) = \psi S$, then the point $(0,0,1)$ attracts all solutions. At the end we have a balance between infected and susceptible of the form
> $$ \alpha \int_0^{\infty} I (t) \, {\rm d} t = \psi \int_0^{\infty} S (t) \, {\rm d} t $$

---

According to the last equation there shall be a balance between infected and susceptible, but I just can't figure out why. I tried integrating $\dot{R}$ over all time but to no avail.

Comment: If it is meant that the balance should hold in the case $\psi(S,I)=\psi S$, then the statement just doesn't hold water: take $\beta=0$. Then the LHS is $I(0)$ and the RHS is $S(0)$, which are different in general. If you insist on some spread, take it small ($\beta\approx 0$) and observe that it can change the values only by $\int_0^\infty \beta SI/N \le \beta \int_0^\infty S$ but $S$ decreases at least exponentially at the rate $\psi$ so that product is much smaller than $S(0)$ when $\beta\to 0$ and it can change nothing. Apparently the author just doesn't know what he/she is talking about...

Comment: Your link is not to the source, but just a screenshot of some page in the source. Please provide the full reference.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and make sense of this "balance between infected and susceptible".

The differential equations are
$$\dot{S}=-\beta SI-\psi S,\;\;\dot{I}=\beta SI-\alpha I,\;\;\dot{R}=\alpha I+\psi S.$$
The sum $N=S+I+R=1$ is time independent. The point $(S,I,R)=(0,0,1)$ is a fixed point, let me assume it's attractive.

Then I just integrate the equation for $\dot{R}$ over all times $t>0$, assuming $R(0)=0$ (no recoveries initially),
$$1=\int_0^\infty \bigl(\alpha I(t)+\psi S(t)\bigr)\,dt.$$
This is not the equation cited in the OP, for reasons which I do not understand.

Comment: Hey Carlo,
thanks to you and fedja for you answers. Your equation $1=\int_{0}^{\infty}(αI(t)+ψS(t))dt$ was exactly my solution which is obviously nowhere near the last equation in my source. So I understand that you can't make sense of what the author meant by that either, is that right?